# issues with dicord bot

Tags: discord, discord.py

#was making a sort of capcha system works on my main account with admin but after going on my alt #account and test getting this error even after giving ult admin

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True, name="cat")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def cat(ctx):
   member = ctx.message.author
   role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="user")
   await member.add_roles(role)
   await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
```

Error:

```
#raise MissingPermissions(missing)
#discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingPermissions: You are missing Manage Messages permission(s) to #run this command.
```

Comment: The error tells you what went wrong...?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why you would need help, the error is just telling you that the account does not have a role with that perm.